# Proving that there exists a subsequence of $(q_n)^\infty_{n=1}$that converges to $l$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

Let $(q_n)^\infty_{n=1}$ be a sequence which maps $\mathbb{N}$ onto $P=\{p \in \mathbb{Q} : 0\leq p \leq 1\}$. Show that if $l\in[0,1]$ then there exists a subsequence $(q_{n_j})^\infty_{j=1}$ which converges to $l$.

***Proof:*** Let $l\in[0,1]\equiv l\in\{q\in\mathbb{Q}: 0\leq q \leq 1\}$. In general:

$[l-1,l+1]\supset[l-\frac{1}{2}, l+\frac{1}{2}]\supset [l-\frac{1}{4}, l+\frac{1}{4}]\supset...$ with $a_0=l-1; b_0=l+1; a_1=l-\frac{1}{2}; b_1=l+\frac{1}{2}...$ such that $a_n=l-\frac{1}{2^n}$ and $b_n=l+\frac{1}{2^n}$.

Since $\frac{1}{2^n}\to0$ as $n\to \infty$, both $a_n$ and $b_n$ go to $l$ as $n\to\infty$.

Each interval $[a_j,b_j]$ contains elements of $\{q_n\}$ for infinitely many $n$, as there are infinitely many rational numbers in a given interval with a positive length. Now we can choose $n_j\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall_{j\in\mathbb{N}}(n_{j+1}\gt n_j)$ and $\{q_{n_j}\}\in[a_j,b_j]$.

Then, $\{q_{n_j}\}\in[a_j,b_j] \iff a_j\leq \{q_{n_j}\}\leq b_j$, and as both $a_n$ and $b_n$ go to $l$ as $n\to\infty$, $\{q_{n_j}\}\to l$ by the sandwich principle. By its surjection, any $l\in[0,1]$ can be chosen such that there exists a corresponding subsequence $\{q_{n_j}\}$ converges to $l$.$\tag*{$\Box$}$

Comment: Even if there are infinitely many accumulation points, it doesn't mean that every point $l$ is an accumulation point. For  example there are infinitely many odd integers but some integers aren't odd.

Comment: Hint: take an arbitrary $l$ and use  a sequence $N_k$ of neigbourhoods of $l$ that shrinks to $\{l\}$ as $k\to \infty$.

Comment: "As there are now infinitely many subsequences $q_{n_{j}}$, there are also infinitely many convergent subsequences $q_{n_{j}}$, and thus also infinitely many limits $l$." - this line is seriously flawed - it is not guaranteed that the limits will be distinct, and if you choose them to be subsequences of your (original, fixed) convergent subsequence, then they are in fact *certainly* all the same. As for formality, it will be much clearer what you mean if you quantify your variables before you use them.

Comment: @Gribouillis Isn't that what I used in the first proof? Or am I in the right direction, but just making some flawed steps and unclear paths?

Comment: The second proof looks much better but there are errors in the beginning. In fact you don't need the beginning. Start directly with the line "such that $a_n=...$". Note that every interval with a positive length contain infinitely many $q_n$ because every rational number is in the sequence.

Comment: @Gribouillis I edited the second part and removed some things. Is the proof now correct?

Comment: You cannot have $[l-1, l] = [l - \frac{1}{2}, l+\frac{1}{2}]$ for example because $l \not = l+\frac{1}{2}$. But all this part is unnecessary. Remove the 2 first paragraphs of the second proof.

Comment: I finally see why I can just start my proof right there. I thought that it would lead to a gap of information but I see that in general, most of it is right and using some theorems, everything is logically correct. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Gribouillis I made a final edit now, could you read through it one more time so I know it is correct? I think I also saw some errors in variables (using $a_n$ first and later $a_j$ for example). Would be greatly appreciated! Again thanks for your help!

Comment: It looks very good now. You can still remove the last sentence. One doesn't need to invoke surjection. It has already been used when you said that every interval contains an infinite number of rationals and that every rational is a member of the $q_n$ sequence.